# How to make Vercel clone submodule?

Tags: vercel

my hexo blog's theme is a git submodule,I want to use Vercel to display my blog.
But clone this project must to command `git submodule init and git submodule update` to clone submodule,Obviously Vercel don't do that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN5nn.png)